# How append works in hdfs? Where the newly created instance of file is placed?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata

I'm a Newbie to Hadoop!

By web search and after going through hadoop guides, it is clear that hdfs doesn't allow us to edit the file but to append some data to existing file, it will be creating a new instance temporarily and append the new data to it.

That being said,

1.would like to know whether the new file or temp is created in the same block or in a different block?

2.What will happen if the file exceeds the previous allocated block size is exceeded?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162943/how-does-hdfs-with-append-works

Hope it helps.