# Spark output filename and append on write

Tags: java, azure, hadoop, apache-spark

I know this question has been asked before but i am unable to get a clear working answer.

```
result.saveAsTextFile(path);
```

1. when using spark saveAsTextFile the output is saved by the name of "part-00", "part-01" etc. 
   Is it possible to change this name to customized name?
2. Is it possible for a saveAsTextFile to append to existing file rather then overwriting it ?

**I am using Java 7 for coding, the output file system would be cloud (Azure, Aws)**

Comment: it is by design that files are split . you can always merge them to a single file http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700068/merge-output-files-after-reduce-phase

Comment: You can do it with a custom OutputFormat, but it will be quite a bit of effort. The file names come from deep in the file writing system. I would suggest you to just accept the file names as they are. And to access the file you can do sc.textFile(filepath). That will work. To merge those partitions split into a single file you can use coalesce.

Comment: Thanks, any comments on append to a file

Comment: @duck, For appending to a file, please refer to the answer  for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162943/how-does-hdfs-with-append-works, and HDInsight on Azure is based on Hortonworks distribution that you can refer to https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/16990/append-in-hdfs.html.

Comment: @MFST the links you provided are not helping, these are just theory explaining how append works. what i required is how can append using spark, a code snipped would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

1) There is no direct support in saveAsTextFile method to control file output name.
You can try using saveAsHadoopDataset to control output file basename.

e.g.: instead of part-00000 you can get yourCustomName-00000.

Keep in mind that you cannot control the suffix 00000 using this method. It is something spark automatically assigns for each partition while writing so that each partition writes to a unique file.

In order to control that too as mentioned above in the comments you have to write your own custom OutputFormat.

```
SparkConf conf=new SparkConf();
conf.setMaster("local").setAppName("yello");
JavaSparkContext sc=new JavaSparkContext(conf);

JobConf jobConf=new JobConf();
jobConf.set("mapreduce.output.basename", "customName");
jobConf.set("mapred.output.dir", "outputPath");

JavaRDD<String> input = sc.textFile("inputDir");
input.saveAsHadoopDataset(jobConf);
```

2) A workaround would be to write output as it is to your output location and use [Hadoop FileUtil.copyMerge](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?class=org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil&method=copyMerge) function to form merged file.